# include files only on particular pages php

Tags: php, include

I am completely new to PHP and have this problem. On every page I am including footer file, and then footer includes a small input form file. I would like the footer to included it on each page besides contactus.php.

Is it doable?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an if like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != '/contactus.php')
   include('footer.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this. Just surround your block of code with an if check, that checks for the current page. Something like this.

```
<?php if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != '/contactus.php') { ?>
    <!-- Your code goes here -->
<? } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your footer file you can use this code:

```
<?php

if($_GET['page'] != "contact")
{   
        include('pages/forms.php');
}

?>
```

This is if your code is something like

```
<?php

include('pages/header.php');

switch($_GET['page'])
{
    case "homepage": include('pages/homepage.php'); break;
    case "blog":     include('pages/blog.php');     break;
    case "contact":  include('pages/contact.php');  break;
    default:         include('pages/404.php');      break;
}

include('pages/footer.php');

?>
```